# Negation of specific statement

Tags: propositional-calculus

**Definition:** We say that $X\subset \mathbb{R}$ is bounded above if $\exists C\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\forall x\in X$ we have $x\leq C$.

$(X \ \text{is bounded above}):=\exists C\in \mathbb{R}((\forall x\in X)\Rightarrow (x\leq C))$

So I want to take the negation of it: $$\neg(X \ \text{is bounded above})\equiv \neg(\exists C\in \mathbb{R}((\forall x\in X)\Rightarrow (x\leq C)))\equiv$$ $$\equiv\forall C\in \mathbb{R} \neg((\forall x\in X)\Rightarrow (x\leq C))$$
But we know that $\neg (P\Rightarrow Q)\equiv P\land \neg Q$ which implies that $$\neg(X \ \text{is bounded above})\equiv \forall C\in \mathbb{R} ((\forall x\in X)\land (x> C)) $$

But I know that the correct negation should be the following: $X\subset \mathbb{R}$ is not bounded above if $\forall C\in \mathbb{R}$ $\exists x\in X$ s.t. $x>C$.

What am I doing wrong in the above?

Answer (score 1):

Right in the begining on the second line. The big quantifier $\forall$ is not part of the implication. It is:

$\exists C\in R (\forall x\in X (x\leq C))$

Edit: Expression $(\forall x\in X) \rightarrow (x\leq C) $ isn't meaningful expression because $(\forall x\in X)$ has no logical value (it is not true-false statement) it is just quantification.

Comment: Why it is not a part of the implication? What it wrong with this statement? I mean this one: $\exists C\in \mathbb{R}((\forall x\in X)\Rightarrow (x\leq C))$

Comment: Thanks! But I have not studied math logic. My knowledge is quite very poor on this subject. Could you give more details why my statement is false.

Comment: You are building formulas (long expressions) from smaller *atomic* formulas. Those are just some statements that are either true or false ($2<3$, seven is even, whatev...) and you build bigger expressions. You can build using connectives. You have two atomic and you say *they are both true* or *one implies the other*...or you can build bigger blog like saying *it is true for every number* or *there is number for which it is true*. But you used $\forall x \in X$ as a first part of implication but this is void. You say *for all x in X  so:* but you should say *´for all x in X this happens so:*.

Comment: Sorry but I am a bit confused with your last sentence.

Comment: I meant that I do not see any difference between "for all $x$ in $X$ so" and "for all $x$ in $X$ this happens so"

Answer (score 1):

If we write definition as
$$(\exists C\in \mathbb{R})(\forall x\in X)(x\leq C)\quad (1)$$
Then negation gives
$$(\forall C\in \mathbb{R})(\exists x\in X)(x> C)\quad (2)$$
Now step by step: using, that $(\forall x\in X)Q(x)$ is same as $(\forall x)(x\in X \Rightarrow Q(x))$ and $(\exists x\in X)Q(x)$ is same as $(\exists x)(x\in X \land Q(x))$, definition $(1)$ can be decoded as
$$(\exists C)\big(C\in \mathbb{R} \land (\forall x)(x\in X \Rightarrow x\leq C)\big)\quad (1)$$
Taking negation gives
$$(\forall C)\big(C\notin \mathbb{R} \lor (\exists x)(x\in X \land x> C)\big)$$
which is
$$(\forall C)\big(C\notin \mathbb{R} \lor (\exists x\in X)( x> C)\big)$$
$$(\forall C)\big(C\in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow (\exists x\in X)( x> C)\big)$$
$$(\forall C\in \mathbb{R})(\exists x\in X)(x> C)\quad (2)$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am reading it right now. But what is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: Your record for definition "$:=$" should be $(\exists C\in \mathbb{R})(\forall x) (x \in X \Rightarrow x\leq C)$

Comment: But it does not explain what is wrong with my record, right? Could you explain it, please?

Comment: In my answer I brought definition of $(\forall x\in X)Q(x)$. Accordingly it your record $(\forall x\in X)\Rightarrow (x\leq C)$ formally should be written as $(\forall x)(x\in X \Rightarrow (\Rightarrow (x\leq C)))$, which, as you can see, have no sense.